# Symmetry and symmetric vacuum in Quantum Field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, symmetry, vacuum, symmetry-breaking

In the start of section 28.2 of Schwartz's Quantum Field theory and the Standard Model, Schwartz states that for a conserved charge, $\hat{Q}$, which generates the corresponding symmetry transformation, we have that $[\hat{H},\hat{Q}]=0$.
Moreover, he states that for a symmetric vacuum (with respect to the symmetry transformation generated by $\hat{Q}$), $|0\rangle_{sym}$ we have
$$\hat{Q}|0\rangle_{sym}=0$$
Other authors state this in words in the lines of "the symmetry transformations leave the vacuum invariant".

But, is the vacuum is invariant under $\hat{Q}$, couldn't we have the more general $\hat{Q}|0\rangle_{sym}=q|0\rangle_{sym}$ for some constant (charge) $q$? This way, the action of $\hat{Q}$ on the symmetric vacuum would give back the vacuum.   This is consistent with $[\hat{H},\hat{Q}]=0$ since by definition the vacuum is the state of lowest energy.

One attempt to answer this question is that if $\hat{Q}|0\rangle_{sym}=q|0\rangle_{sym}$, then we can just redefine $\hat{Q}$ to be $\hat{Q'}=\hat{Q}-q$ for all the $\hat{Q}$s that generate the symmetries of the vacuum. Is this all there is? A trivial redefinition done for convenience?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schwartz's statement is correct; I think your statement results from a confusion between finite symmetries and symmetry generators.

To make this concrete, consider a rotation operator $\hat{R}(\theta)$. The state that the vacuum is invariant under rotations is
$$\hat{R}(\theta) |0 \rangle = |0 \rangle.$$
But the rotation operator can also be written as 
$$\hat{R}(\theta) = e^{i \theta \hat{J}}$$
where $\hat{J}$ is some angular momentum operator. Expanding to first order in $\theta$, we have
$$(1 + i \theta \hat{J}) |0 \rangle = |0 \rangle$$
which implies that
$$\hat{J} |0 \rangle = 0.$$
In Schwartz's statement, $\hat{Q}$ is a symmetry generator like $\hat{J}$. Invariance under $\hat{Q}$ means that the *exponential* of $\hat{Q}$, not $\hat{Q}$ itself, leaves the vacuum invariant.

Comment: Ah, nice! Just a question: is there a more general argument for not adding a constant? Because, in analogy with what I argued in the question, at least for me it makes sense to also say that $\hat{R}(\theta)|0\rangle=\lambda(\theta)|0\rangle$ means that rotations leave the vacuum invariant (up to an overall number $\lambda$ that possibly depends on $\theta$; we can possibly take to have modulus equal to one in order to preserve the norm). This way, the argument with the redefinition goes through (or I am missing something)

Comment: @TheQuantumMan One reason is that, in symmetry breaking, you typically don't have $\hat{Q} |0 \rangle$ being a multiple of $|0 \rangle$. It's instead some other state entirely.